# Add multiple classes to @media tag, clean efficient coding for CSS?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive

I'm pretty new to CSS so trying to learn everyday, anyway I have the below code with @Media tag, instead of splitting it up as 2 media tag how do I just combine the classes in 1?

Current code is below, it works but its repeating code.

```
 @media (max-width: 767px){
      .table-fluid td {
          word-break: unset !important;
  }
  }

  @media (max-width: 767px){
      .modal-content {
          width: 92% !important;
  }
  }
```

I want to do something like, I hope you get what I mean, I prefer `@media (max-width: 767px)` to be defined once, please advise for a cleaner and efficient way?

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
.table-fluid td {
word-break: unset !important;}
.modal-content {
width: 92% !important;}
```

Comment: except for the very last closing bracket missing, that's correct code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 @media (max-width: 767px){
      .table-fluid td {
          word-break: unset !important;
      }
      .modal-content {
          width: 92% !important;
      }
  }

@media (max-with: 900px and min-width: 800px){
   //new media css
}
```

You can write all the id`s and classes you want into the media tag. If you want to make a css style for a different media size, just open a new one.

TIP: Write all @media tag`s on the very bottom of the script.

TIP 2: If ypu are trying to make a web page for different devices, you should make in movile first mode, i´ll let you a [link](https://medium.com/@Vincentxia77/what-is-mobile-first-design-why-its-important-how-to-make-it-7d3cf2e29d00) so you can read more about it.

TIP 3: On html head, write the next tags:

```
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge" >
   <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1" >
```

Comment: The tips are from my experience working with  media tag, hope they are helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like the following:

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
  .table-fluid td {
     word-break: unset !important;
  }
  .modal-content {
     width: 92% !important;
  }
}
```

> These style classes will be rendered while screens that are 767px or
>   less.